# Sorting bibliography by shorttitle?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, sorting

I'm writing a report that cites extensive primary sources without an author field. To avoid verbosity, I make sure the "shorttitle" field is what gets printed in the text.

Normally it's very hard to identify short titles in the bibliography; however, my bibliography is printing short titles first, before the full reference. This makes it helpful to find the reference so it's all well and good. For example,

```
@report{example_1965,
    title = {This is an example report blah blah},
    shorttitle ={Example Report},
    date = {1965-8-27},
}
```

gets printed like so in the bibliography:

```
Example Report (August 27, 1965). This is an example report blah blah.
```

There's just one problem: the bibliography is still sorting alphabetically by title, *not* by shorttitle. As a result, everything is out of order. Example:

```
Example Report 2 (August 27, 1965). A This is an example report blah blah.

Example Report 3 (August 27, 1965). B This is an example report blah blah.

Example Report 1 (August 27, 1965). C This is an example report blah blah.
```

Ideally reports would be ordered by their short title (number) since this appears first in each reference. How can I instruct `biblatex` to sort by "shorttitle" rather than "title"?

I'm really stuck on this problem after a lot of searching. There's some hint that an option like "label" might work, but I'd rather not go through the list of 3000+ sources to find and change all the relevant "shorttitle"s into "label"s. Is there a solution I'm overlooking?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{filecontents}{\abibliography.bib}
    @report{example_1965_1,
    title = {C This is an example report blah blah},
    shorttitle ={Example Report 1},
    date = {1965-8-27},
}
    @report{example_1965_2,
    title = {B This is an example report blah blah},
    shorttitle ={Example Report 2},
    date = {1965-8-29},
}
    @report{example_1965_3,
    title = {A This is an example report blah blah},
    shorttitle ={Example Report 3},
    date = {1965-8-28},
}
\end{filecontents}

% some customizations my publisher requires
\usepackage[
natbib=true,
maxcitenames=2, 
maxbibnames=99,
style=authoryear,
backend=bibtex, 
sorting=nyt, 
citetracker=true,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
refsegment=chapter
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{abibliography.bib}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[incollection]{useeditor=false}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 

\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{6}}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{issn}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{doi}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{doi}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{url}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{url}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {}
    {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}


\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{some_chapter}

blah blah \citep{example_1965_3} and \citep{example_1965_2} and \citep{example_1965_1}

% bibliographies
    \clearpage

% more required customizations
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\large\bfseries\filcenter{#1}} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

\begin{singlespace}
    \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}  
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE doesn't compile, there are some errors and missing packages. Most of the errors can be resolved by making the MWE simpler, remove `singlespace` environmnets and title formats etc. Regarding your question: is there a reason you use `bibtex` as backend, instead of `biber`?

Comment: Specifically, it is possible to define a custom sorting scheme where you list the sorting order of the fields, where you can put `shorttitle` first. However, this is only supported with `biber` as backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `backend=bibtex,` your options to customise the sorting are fairly limited. The only thing that is officially supported would be to set the `sorttitle` field (to the same value as `shorttitle`), but that requires additional work and causes data duplication.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex, 
  natbib=true,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2, 
  maxbibnames=99,
  citetracker=true,
  doi=false,
  url=false,
  isbn=false,
%  refsegment=chapter,
]{biblatex}


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[incollection]{useeditor=false}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} 

\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{6}}}

\DeclareListInputHandler{list}{\def\NewValue{}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {}
    {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{example_1965_1,
  title      = {C This is an example report blah blah},
  shorttitle = {Example Report 1},
  sorttitle  = {Example Report 1},
  date       = {1965-08-27},
}
@report{example_1965_2,
  title      = {B This is an example report blah blah},
  shorttitle = {Example Report 2},
  sorttitle  = {Example Report 2},
  date       = {1965-08-29},
}
@report{example_1965_3,
  title      = {A This is an example report blah blah},
  shorttitle = {Example Report 3},
  sorttitle  = {Example Report 3},
  date       = {1965-08-28},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
blah blah \citep{example_1965_3} and \citep{example_1965_2} and \citep{example_1965_1}

\printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Report 1//Example Report 2//Example Report 3 in the bibliography]

---

Unless you have a very good reason to stick with BibTeX I suggest you check out Biber. Change `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,` and tell your editor to run Biber for you ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)).

With Biber it is almost trivial to change the selected sorting scheme `nyt` to also take into account the `shorttitle` field. We just need to insert `\field{shorttitle}` in the right place ([the original definition can be found in ll. 1507-1534 of `biblatex.def` (v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1507)).

Note that Biber will complain about your `date` fields as they are not in valid ISO 8601 format. Month and day must be given with two digits (padded with zeros). So `date = {1965-8-27},` should be `date = {1965-08-27},` etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber, 
  natbib=true,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2, 
  maxbibnames=99,
  citetracker=true,
  doi=false,
  url=false,
  isbn=false,
%  refsegment=chapter,
]{biblatex}


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[incollection]{useeditor=false}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} 

\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{6}}}

\DeclareListInputHandler{list}{\def\NewValue{}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {}
    {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{shorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@report{example_1965_1,
  title      = {C This is an example report blah blah},
  shorttitle = {Example Report 1},
  date       = {1965-08-27},
}
@report{example_1965_2,
  title      = {B This is an example report blah blah},
  shorttitle = {Example Report 2},
  date       = {1965-08-29},
}
@report{example_1965_3,
  title      = {A This is an example report blah blah},
  shorttitle = {Example Report 3},
  date       = {1965-08-28},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
blah blah \citep{example_1965_3} and \citep{example_1965_2} and \citep{example_1965_1}

\printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to try with biber. You overestimate my competency though... there's only one biblatex.def on my system and for some reason I don't have permissions to edit it. Could you please elaborate on how to add the requisite line?

Comment: @beddotcom Oh sorry for the confusion. Do **not** edit `biblatex.def`. It is enough to have the `\DeclareSortingTemplate{nyt}` in your preamble. The second code block works as-is without change to any already installed files. You can simply copy-and-paste the bits of the preamble into your own document and things should work (if you use Biber).

Comment: I couldn't actually get this method to work with my live document and switching to biber caused more problems than it solved for me, but the first bibtex-compatible suggestion (though painstaking) worked. Just glad that the problem is solved! Hope moewe's kind answer is useful to others in the future.